# python 2.7.6 printing string location in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

How do you print the location of a string in a list?

my script is:

```
plants = 'apples,  beans,  carrots , dates , eggplant'.split(', ')
UI = raw_input ('Please enter a fruit or vegetable. ')
for i in list(plants)
```

The expected outcome is:

Enter the name of a fruit or vegetable: carrots

carrots is item 3 in the list

Sorry its supposed to be:

UI is item _ in the list.
Lets say they enter dates, it would be:
Dates is item four on the list.

Comment: Do you want us to write all your homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [`.index()` method](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists):

> Return the index in the list of the first item whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

```
plants = 'apples,  beans,  carrots , dates , eggplant'
plants = [x.strip() for x in plants.split(',')]  # split and remove spaces in names
UI = raw_input ('Please enter a fruit or vegetable. ')
if UI in plants:
    print "%s is item %s in the list" % (UI, plants.index(UI))
else:
    print "%s isn't in the list" % UI
```

Comment: It is saying that all my inputs are not in the list

Comment: Change like this here, delete space before the comma or use split: 


    plants = 'apples, beans, carrots, dates, eggplant'.split(', ')

Comment: @jak10101 should be fixed. It was due to spaces not removed in the split.

Comment: It would be more beautiful if you can merge the first two line. I mean split()+strip() altogether :)

Comment: @S.M.AlMamun Yep, indeed. Done.

Comment: @MaximeLorant: you beat me, man! I was going to post it but :)